# How to load Scripts into a partial view MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I have an MVC application using Razor. I have a partial view that uses a jquery script. The jquery script only works when it is referenced in the partial view and not in the _layout view. When using firebug, I cannot see the script when it is referenced in the partial view. Is there a way to reference all scripts in the _layout and have it work in all views and partial views?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your `ActionResult`, instead of doing `return PartialView()` instead of `return View()`. That will allow you to render the scripts.

Comment: ` instead of doing return PartialView() instead of return View()` what does it mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe you can create a bundle in your bundle.config of those jquery scripts and call in your _layout as:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/NameBundle").Include(
             "~/SomeFolder/Scripts/YourJquery.js"));
```

And in your _layout.cshtml:

```
<body> 
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/NameBundle")
</body>
```

This way everybody who get the _Layout will also get those Jquery.

I dont recommend to call mixed jquerys in other views once you put in your _Layout